# Azure table with different entities in development storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Still searching for an answer to this question:

It's my understanding that there is no requirement that there be any structural or type similarity between different entities in a table in Azure storage. But what about development storage? I recently read that this is not true as development storage requires a schema because it stores the data using SQL Server Express.

Can someone confirm this. Also if this is the case then how could I use Dev storage to model different entities within a table in production?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Gordon,
Development Storage uses SQL server under the hood to simulate the live azure storage. (It must store the data somewhere). Think of it as an emulator. You use the same API to access live storage or development storage. You are not required to use a schema for development storage.
Think of it as changing a connection string from a staging server to a production server.

Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433135.aspx) for more detailed information:

Comment: Thanks for your advice with this. I would like to login and mark the question as answered but I am not sure how to do this as I entered this question without login. My apology to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to use a schema in production, but all objects in a development storage table must have the same set of columns (see [here](http://deeperdesign.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/azure-table-storage-what-a-pain-in-the-ass/)).  I'd suggest using multiple tables in development, and switching to one table in production if you need to (maybe use a configuration value to indicate what table tables to use?)

Comment: Thanks for your advice and for the links that you provided. I checked out those links and have them bookmarked. I notice one of the link points to a microsoft document which has now been updated. Hopefully recent code changes have fixed some of the problems with the dev storage server.